# Why isn't my algorithm to make a Koch curve working?

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
import turtle as t

def kochCurve(length,degree):
    if degree == 0:
        t.forward(length)
    else:
        if length >= 3:
            length = length/3
            degree = degree - 1
            kochCurve(length,degree)
            t.right(60)
            kochCurve(length,degree)
            t.right(240)
            kochCurve(length,degree)
            t.right(60)
            kochCurve(length,degree)
            

kochCurve(100,50)
```

When I run this code it opens the turtle window and the arrow just spins around before the program stops, why is this?

Comment: You never execute sth like `t.forward()`.

Comment: Well, you *do* call `t.forward()`, but only after dividing the length by 3 fifty times, so the distance the turtle moves is roughly the size of an atom.

Comment: You have written a recursive function, but seem to have used two base cases.

Comment: In your own words: if you call `kochCurve(100, 50)`, what do you expect should be the value of `length` once `degree` has reached zero? What do you think should happen, if `degree` *isn't* zero, but `length` is less than three? Did you try to trace the logic of the code in order to see what is happening? Did you try drawing simpler curves, for example by using a much smaller `degree` value (say, 3)? What happens as you increase that value?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For a recursive function you only need one base case. You can use `if length > <value>:`

This program produces something like a Koch curve:

```py
import turtle as t

def kochCurve(length):
    if length >= 3:
        length = length/3
        kochCurve(length)
        t.right(60)
        kochCurve(length)
        t.right(240)
        kochCurve(length)
        t.right(60)
        kochCurve(length)
    else:
        t.forward(length)


kochCurve(100)
```

**Update:**

So the `degree` parameter really isn't useful because `length` works well.

Using this calling code, you get the so-called Koch snowflake:

```
kochCurve(100)
t.left(120)
kochCurve(100)
t.left(120)
kochCurve(100)
t.hideturtle()
t.done()
```

Answer (score -1):

It's clear what you are trying to achieve, but consider what happens for a simpler case, calling your function with `kochCurve(10, 3)`:

- First call, `degree` is not `0`, and `length` is `10`, so `>= 3`; that's as expected, length gets divided by `3` and the function is called with `kochCurve(3.33.., 2)`
- Second call, `degree` is `2` and still not `0`, and `length` is still greater than `3`, so the function is called again with `kochCurve(1.11.., 1)`
- However, `degree` still isn't `0`, but `length` no longer is greater than or equal to `3` the function does nothing and returns. The next instruction is to turn the cursor.

This process continues. The function either does nothing because neither condition is `True`, or it proceeds to turn the cursor - which is exactly the behaviour you're describing.

The main problem is your recursive function doesn't have a proper base case.

However, there's a second problem: since you divide `length` by 3 on every recursive call, the value of `length` quickly diminishes below `1`. Although the Python turtle does allow movement smaller than a pixel (which may not be true for any turtle program out there), the progress will be very hard to see initially and still resemble a spinning cursor.

Try running your code with more reasonable parameters like `kochCurve(1000, 4)` first.

There's several ways of fixing your code. Removing the `if length >= 3` easiest, but you probably wanted to limit the recursion depth for lengths that get arbitrarily small?

If you do want to keep the explicit degree, but also limit by length:

```
def kochCurve(length, degree):
    if degree == 0 or length < 3:
        t.forward(length)
    else:
        length = length / 3
        degree = degree - 1
        kochCurve(length, degree)
        t.right(60)
        kochCurve(length, degree)
        t.right(240)
        kochCurve(length, degree)
        t.right(60)
        kochCurve(length, degree)
```

A final remark on style: `kochCurve` is not the preferred naming in Python, consider using `koch_curve` instead. We all have preferences, but it makes the most sense to use the preferences of whoever wrote the language.